# Having problems with RecyclerView in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am new at android development.I am developing an application which generates bills. i created three activities i.e., one is MainActivity, other is Display Bills activity with a **RecyclerView** and a floating action button and third activity which is for adding bills which is displayed when user clicks the FAB button from second activity.
i am trying to get the data from activity three and display them in the recyclerview which is in activity two and i want to do this action when the add button on the third activity is clicked.. everytime i run this code, the app crashes.
Any help will be appreciated.

This is my DisplayBills activity

```
public class DisplayBills extends AppCompatActivity {


public Button mAddBtn;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private CustomRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private EditText mOrder;
private EditText mDate;
private EditText mName;
private EditText mTdsin;
private EditText mTdsout;
private EditText mAmount;

private List<Data> mData = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_bills);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mAddBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_bill);

    mAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Initializing views.
            mOrder = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_order_no);
            mDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_date);
            mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_c_name);
            mTdsin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_tds_in);
            mTdsout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_tds_out);
            mAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_amount);
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

            // If the size of views will not change as the data changes.
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            // Setting the LayoutManager.
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            // Setting the adapter.
            mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        // Called when add button is clicked.
        public void addItem(View view) {

            // Add data locally to the list.
            Data dataToAdd = new Data(
                    Integer.parseInt(mOrder.getText().toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(mDate.getText().toString()),
                    mName.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(mTdsin.getText().toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(mTdsout.getText().toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(mAmount.getText().toString()));
            mData.add(dataToAdd);

            // Update adapter.
            mAdapter.addItem(mData.size() - 1, dataToAdd);
        }
    });


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AddNewBill.class);

            // Start DisplayBills Activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_bills, menu);
        return true;
    }
 }
```

This is my XML for DisplayBills which is surrounded by a Coordinator layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my AddNewBills activity

```
public class AddNewBill extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_bill);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
}
```

This is XML for AddNewBills activity which is also surrounded by a Coordinator Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_order_no"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_order"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/order"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_date"
            android:inputType="date"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cusname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/date"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_c_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_cname" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cusname"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_tds_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/hint_tdsin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tin"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_tds_out"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/hint_tdsout" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tamount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tout"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_amount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/hint_amount" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_add_bill"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_add_bill"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**this is my logcat**

```
    12-24 15:20:02.976 2118-2118/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-24 15:20:43.706 2128-2128/me.yash.basiclogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: me.yash.basiclogin, PID: 2128
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.yash.basiclogin/me.yash.basicloginmaterialdesign.DisplayBills}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at me.yash.basicloginmaterialdesign.DisplayBills.onCreate(DisplayBills.java:44)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
12-24 15:20:51.659 339-373/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b1f5347 me.yash.basiclogin/me.yash.basicloginmaterialdesign.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: i dont know how to get the logcat @Android

Comment: your app is crashing that red error in the logcat... not this

Comment: i am sorry, plz help me coz i am new to all this and dont know much about this.. @Android

Comment: u r using android studio??? @yashpandit]

Comment: yes i am using Android Studio 1.5.1 @Android

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because your calling Button.setOnClickListener(View.onClickListener) when you have not defined R.id.btn_add_bill and your trying to add a listener to a non existing UI element here:

```
 mAddBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_bill); 
 mAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View view) { //...}});
```

So to fix your issue add a Button with R.id.btn_add_bill to your activity layout for display bills or move this code to the class that and it will fix your issue.

**Edit**
It appears you have defined

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_add_bill" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/btn_add_bill" 
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" 
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

But its not in the layout for display bills which is where you are trying to add its listener

```
public class DisplayBills extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button mAddBtn;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private CustomRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private EditText mOrder;
private EditText mDate;
private EditText mName;
private EditText mTdsin;
private EditText mTdsout;
private EditText mAmount;

private List<Data> mData = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_bills);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //.. Removed the mAddBtn, since it does not exist in your layout

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AddNewBill.class);

            // Start DisplayBills Activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_bills, menu);
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Whatever you removed from above you need to use in your other activity which actually has the Button defined in its layout file.

Comment: where should i write the code for onClickListener for button. In the activity where the recyclerview is or on the other activity? @inner_class7

Comment: @yashpandit yes in the other activity

Comment: app still crashes my friend.. do you have any other solution?? @inner_class7

Comment: @YashPandit updated my answer, please read carefully. you are defining a button in code which does not exist in your layout file. remove that code from activity and add to the activity which you actually have the button in the layout

Comment: did the same what you told me to do but it still is not working.that is why i told you to give me an alternate solution...

Comment: @YashPandit what do you mean not working? are you still getting a crash?

Comment: please help me... @inner_class7